# How to Run Python Code in Android for ESP-32 Object Detection?

Tags: python, android, flask, object-detection, esp32

I've been working on my CAM ESP-32 object detection model for a while. It consists of an ESP-32 CAM that detects objects through Python, first I have to activate the IP of the ESP-32 with the Arduino IDE.
The problem is that I want the ESP-32 to be portable and not always connected to the PC, which is where the Python code is executed. I thought about having this code executed in a phone app or uploading the code to Flask. But I don't see it possible, What can I do?

Python Code:

````
import cv2 #opencv
import urllib.request 
import numpy as np
import firebase_admin 
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db


cred = credentials.Certificate("")


firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL': ''
})

firebase_db = db.reference()


url = 'http://192.168.0.000/800x600.jpg'
#url = 'http://192.168.1.6/'
winName = 'ESP32 CAMERA'
cv2.namedWindow(winName,cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
#scale_percent = 80 # percent of original size    

classNames = []
classFile = 'coco.names'
with open(classFile,'rt') as f:
    classNames = f.read().rstrip('\n').split('\n')

configPath = 'ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt'
weightsPath = 'frozen_inference_graph.pb'

net = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(weightsPath,configPath)
net.setInputSize(320,320)
#net.setInputSize(480,480)
net.setInputScale(1.0/127.5)
net.setInputMean((127.5, 127.5, 127.5))
net.setInputSwapRB(True)

while(1):
    imgResponse = urllib.request.urlopen (url) #abrimos el URL
    imgNp = np.array(bytearray(imgResponse.read()),dtype=np.uint8)
    img = cv2.imdecode (imgNp,-1) #decodificamos

    img = cv2.rotate(img, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE) # vertical
    #img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #black and white

    classIds, confs, bbox = net.detect(img, confThreshold=0.5)
    print(classNames[classIds.flatten()[0] - 1]) if len(classIds) != 0 else None  

    if len(classIds) != 0:
        for classId, confidence, box in zip(classIds.flatten(), confs.flatten(), bbox):
            className = classNames[classId - 1]
            print(f'Objeto detectado: {className}')

            detection_data = {
                "object_name": className,
            }

            # Enviar los datos de detección de objetos a Firebase
            firebase_db.child('detections').set(detection_data)

    if len(classIds) != 0:
        for classId, confidence, box in zip(classIds.flatten(), confs.flatten(), bbox):
            cv2.rectangle(img, box, color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=3)  
            cv2.putText(img, classNames[classId - 1], (box[0] + 10, box[1] + 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1,
                        (0, 255, 0), 2)


    cv2.imshow(winName,img) 

    tecla = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if tecla == 27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
firebase_admin.delete_app(firebase_admin.get_app()) 
```


I've tried Micropython already and didn't work
````

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.